# "GET / HTTP/1.1" requests getting 404 from malicious agents and bots?

Tags: web-crawlers, security, 404, logs

I was checking my server logs and I see some requests simply for `"GET / HTTP/1.1"` are getting 404 error but only from seemingly malicious users and bots. I thought 404 was only server-side issue? Legitimate users around same timestamp get 200 response. Is there any problem with my server or are malicious users doing something that can generate 404 from client-side ?